# Is it the driver or the workers who reads the text file when sc.textfile is used?

Tags: scala, file, hadoop, apache-spark, io

I am wondering how is sc.textfile used in Spark. My guess is that the driver reads a portion of the file at a time, and distributes the read text to the workers, to process. Or is it that the workers read the text directly themselves from the file without the involvement of the driver?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The driver looks at file metadata - check that it exists, check what files are in the directory if it's a directory, and check their sizes. It then sends tasks to workers, who do the actual reading of the file contents. The communication is essentially "you read this file, starting at this offset, for this length."

HDFS splits large files into blocks, and spark will (usually/often) split tasks according to blocks, so the process of skipping to that offset will be efficient.

Other filesystems tend to operate similarly, though not always. Compression can also mess with this process if the codec is not splittable.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thank you Joe for clarifying my doubt also. Do you you know that if "Driver" is not reading then in below log, why broadcast variables are created and what they store ? MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 127.4 KB, free 269.0 KB)
19/09/16 12:32:30 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 13.9 KB, free 282.9 KB)
19/09/16 12:32:30 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on localhost:52542 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 1122.0 MB)
19/09/16 12:32:30 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from textFile at

Answer (score 0):

`textfile` creates an RDD, as mentioned in the [ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets):

> Text file RDDs can be created using SparkContext’s textFile method.

There is also this note:

> If using a path on the local filesystem, the file must also be
>   accessible at the same path on worker nodes. Either copy the file to
>   all workers or use a network-mounted shared file system.

which implies that your guess about the driver parsing the file and then distributing the data to the slaves is wrong.

Comment: OK, this begs then the question, how the workers synchronize to read the file line by line, without the help of the driver? Assume that the file is in the HDFS, not local.

Comment: I didn't say that the driver is inactive in the process. The internal mechanism of [tag:spark] defines that @pythonic.

Comment: OK, the driver helps in creating the RDD, but I'm assuming that the file is huge, say 1 Tera byte. Now how such huge data gets processed. Its not that the RDD is spread by the driver for the whole data. It must be read portion by portion. I'm still confused about the whole thing.

Comment: Every worker reads its portion, that's why the file itself must be in place in all the workers @pythonic.

Comment: This would be only possible if HDFS allows random reading of the files. Does HDFS allow such reading?